# Lazy evaluation unexpected behaviour

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I was doing the exercises on Streams in the book "Functional Programming in Scala" and was a little confused by some behaviour. We have a Stream trait defined as follows:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A] {

}
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
  lazy val head = hd
  lazy val tail = tl
  Cons(() => head, () => tail)
}
def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty
def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}
```

And then say I do the following:

```
def test(i: Int) = {println("i: " + i); i}

val stream = cons(test(1), cons(test(2), cons(test(3), empty)))
```

Now when I create the stream this way the call to test(1) actually gets evaluated. Can someone tell me why this one is evaluated and not test(2) and test(3)?

Comment: I tried your code on 2.10.4 and there is no evaluation (at least, no "i: .." output). I also don't see [any such output on scalafiddle](http://scalafiddle.net/console/e254457f7497c00fbb0d2bb4ac36487b)

Comment: Turns out to be an issue with Scala 2.9. Does not occur once you upgrade to 2.10

Comment: Do you have a reference to a relevant bug/change? Post an answer and accept it, then.